# Adding extra contour lines using 2D contour plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I am creating a two-dimensional contour plot with matplotlib. Using the documentation provided http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html, such a contour plot can be created by

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
```

which outputs the following plot.
[image]

The documentation details how to manually label certain contours (or "lines") on the existing plot. My question is how to create more contour lines than those shown.

For example, the plot shown has two bivariate gaussians. The upper right has three contour lines, at `0.5`, `1.0`, and `1.5`.

How could I add contour lines at say `0.75` and `1.25`?

Also, I should be able to zoom in and (in principle) add dozens of dozens of contour lines from (for example) `1.0` and `1.5`. How does one do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To draw isolines at specified level values, set the `levels` parameter in [`.contour`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour):

```
levels = np.arange(-1.0,1.5,0.25)
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=levels)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

plt.figure()
levels = np.arange(-1.0,1.5,0.25)
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=levels)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('levels = {}'.format(levels.tolist()))
plt.show()
```

[image]

[The sixth figure here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) uses this method to draw isolines at `levels = np.arange(-1.2, 1.6, 0.2)`.

---

To zoom in, set the `x` limits and `y` limits of the desired region:

```
plt.xlim(0, 3)
plt.ylim(0, 2)
```

and to draw, say, 24 automatically-chosen levels, use

```
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 24)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)

plt.figure()
N = 24
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, N)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('{} levels'.format(N))
plt.xlim(0, 3)
plt.ylim(0, 2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[The third figure here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) uses this method to draw 6 isolines.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically set labels for all contours? How would one do this?

Comment: Take a look at the examples, [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_label_demo.html).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I am asking a simpler question: let's say I wanted `plt.show()` to always return contours with each numerical value labeled. Isn't there a way to set this behavior via `plt.clabel(CS, etc.)`? The example given creates a "label class" in order to pass through labels of a certain format---I'm happy with the format given.

Comment: Doesn't every contour (isoline) already get labeled? If you are happy with the format, what needs to be changed?

Comment: No, by default it doesn't. That what confuses me. The original plot may be labeled, but if I zoom in on certain regions (setting `x` limits and `y` limits), there are no labels. 
The example given doesn't solve this issue. Perhaps I should open a new question....

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I know the answer to your question.

Comment: I've opened a new question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503894/how-to-set-as-default-matplotlib-contour-plot-to-always-label-contours